# A bracket + dot syntax issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, syntax, cocos2d-iphone

I have been working with Objective C for a couple of months now and this has been my first time seeing this type of syntax in objective c. I think I know the equivalent of it but I wanted to be sure.

Specifically, the code looks like this

```
float imageHeight = [player texture].contentSize.height;
```

What is the '[player texture].contentSize.height equivalent to? 
I know that the dot and bracket syntax can be the same thing

```
something.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[something setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

The above two are pretty much the same..

So is this what's happening in my first example? I just have never seen a mix of bracket and dot syntax into one.

Thank's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
float imageHeight = [player texture].contentSize.height;
```

This is probably the same thing as:

```
float imageHeight = [[player texture] contentSize].height;
```

Dot syntax translates to a call of the appropriate property accessor method when it's applied to object pointers. When applied to structures, it's a direct access of one of the fields of that structure.

So, assuming that `[player texture]` returns a pointer to an object (probably an image), the first use of dot syntax accesses that object's `contentSize` property. If `-contentSize` also returns an object pointer, then the next use would also translate to a call of an accessor. More likely, though, the `contentSize` property is a NSSize, and NSSize is a structure with `width` and `height` fields. So the second use of dot syntax most likely retrieves the `height` field from that structure.

Mixing the two different meanings of dot syntax works fine for *getting* a value, but you'll get an error if you try to use it to *set* values. If my assumptions in the previous paragraph are correct, you can't do this:

```
[player texture].contentSize.height = 50;
```

Comment: -1 incorrect. `-texture` might return a `CGRect`, or it could return an object whose `-contentSize` returns a `CGSize`, or `-contentSize` could return an object with a `height` property. Ergo, your assumption that they are equivalent is almost definitely false.

Comment: Hmm.. so what am I looking at here exactly?

Comment: @DaveDeLong Right, I relized that after I considered that `height` is a likely field of a NSSize struct. I've tried to explain the two uses of dot syntax here, as well as clearly state my assumptions. Armed with that understanding, the OP should be able to make sense of things even if my assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: I updated my vote too... this ambiguity is why we follow the google coding guidelines and don't use the Objective-C 2.0 "dot-syntax" syntactic sugar.

Comment: Yeah Caleb, it makes sense. What I'm doing is I'm getting the contentSize of an images height and dividing it by 2. 

Would this also work though . 

[[[player texture]contentSize ] height]; ?

Comment: If `contentSize` is an object with a `height` property, sure. If it's a NSSize or other struct, no. When in doubt, try not to do too much in one line. If you think the code could be misunderstood, try breaking it up into separate statements, e.g.: `NSSize size = [[player texture] contentSize]; float newHeight = size.height / 2;`